# VB.net Msaccess Retrieving data where DATE is BEHIND/LESS THAN the DATE TODAY

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am creating a project to be defend next week about a gym management system. the problem is, i cant inform the user if there is an expired promo. i used these query but its not displaying the right data

```
If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
  con.Open()
End If

Try
  Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT MemberID,Nickname,PromoStatus,PromoStart,PromoEnd FROM Members WHERE PromoEnd < now() AND PromoStatus = 'Active'", con)
  Dim dt As New DataTable
  da.Fill(dt)
  MembersDataGridView.DataSource = dt
  con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

I tried these codes and its not displaying the data where the PromoEnd is less than today/ the PromoEnd is behind the date today. i tried also the

```
SELECT MemberID,Nickname,PromoStatus,PromoStart,PromoEnd FROM Members WHERE PromoEnd < '"& dateandtime.today.date &"' AND PromoStatus = 'Active'", con
```

still its not retrieving the right data. thank u for your helps and any suggestions.
ps: shortdate format is what im using for the dates. (0/0/0000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should i change it as dateandtime in the msaccess?

Yes, *always* store date and time as data type DateTime.

Then your SQL can be reduced to:

```
"SELECT MemberID, Nickname, PromoStatus, PromoStart, PromoEnd FROM Members WHERE PromoEnd < Date() AND PromoStatus = 'Active'"
```

Comment: Thank you sir!! my system is now notifying the user if there is an expired promos. thank you so much <3

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand your requirements if you don't provide a sample data set or your expected results.  However, `now()` is not valid SQL, and in MS Access, dates in queries are delmited by the `#` character.  Try something like this (air code):

```
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(" SELECT MemberID,Nickname,PromoStatus,PromoStart,PromoEnd"
                                   + " FROM Members"
                                   + " WHERE PromoEnd < #" + DateTime.Now.ToString("m/d/yyyy") + "#"
                                   + " AND PromoStatus = 'Active'", con)
```

Comment: thanks mate. in addition, my datatype for the date is text. should i change it as dateandtime in the msaccess?

Comment: Yes. Dates should almost never be stored as strings, and if you do so, you will not get the results you might expect.  For example, an expression that compares strings such as `"1/1/2016" < "4/2/2001"` would evaluate to `true`. Also, if your "date" column is a `string` type, the code I posted will probably return an error.

Comment: Thank you sir! i changed it as dateandtime as what you said and its now working. thank u for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try
        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT MemberID,Nickname,PromoStatus,PromoStart,PromoEnd FROM Members WHERE PromoEnd < now() AND PromoStatus = 'Active'", con)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        MembersDataGridView.DataSource = dt
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

my system is now working as what it should be. ive done what sir gustav and mjh said.